# How do SQL sServer and Crystal Reports link together for case...then 0?

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, case

I'm new to CR & SQL Server. I'm trying to understand how you can code a select case statement with "case some-condition then 0" and "case some-other-condition then 1" and have it connect in Crystal reports....if I want a particular year of data to show, how do I use this particular style of case statement in the SQL Server coding and how do I get it to connect to variable names in CR?

Comment: The same can be done using Crystal Reports Formula also. You can import all the records using Database Expert and can write formula as per your conditions to filter the records.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bare on specifics but hopefully this helps.  In sqlserver a case statement works like this.  You can get a lot more detail [via books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You didn't specify which version of SQL Server so I linked to 2008 R2.

```
SELECT
      SomeColumn,
      SomeOtherColumn,
(CASE MyColumn
    WHEN 'First' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Second' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Third' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END) AS MyNewColumn /* the name can be same as original column if you want */
FROM MyTable
```

As for mapping the value to Crystal you can treat MyNewColumn just like any other column name with regards to comparing to parameters etc.